# PYTHON -> Creating a module that prints something when imported

Tags: python, printing, import, python-import

When I import a module in Python I usually proceed as follows:

```
from math import pi

pi
```

Answer -> 3.14159265

Is there any way that one could create a module that just after imported prints something?

For example:

```
import module

Answer -> Hello world!
```

Comment: Modules are executed by default when they are imported. This is why most are protected by `if __name__ == '__main__':` to _prevent_ this happening.

Comment: Although it's possible by adding simple print statement to your module, it's very bad design. Consider e.g. someone importing your module and wondering why there's your output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the print statement in your module and you will achieve exactly what you describe.

To follow up on your comment this is how your module should look like:

```
print 'hello'
#Here define functions of the module 
...

if __name__ == "__main__":     
    print 'world'
```

Here you can find more info on this syntax: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: Works fantastic! And any way it could print different messages deppending on how you open the file? For example: if you are in python command line -> import module -> it prints "hello". if you are in your system console and do -> python module.py -> it prints "world!"

Comment: Everything works fantastic. Thank you very very much.